# How to wait for an Autoreset event to occur before taking any other action?

Tags: c#, multithreading, autoresetevent

This is about the `AutoResetEvent` in C#. I tried to read other answers but I could not make sense and apply to my scenario. I am not writing any threading application. Just a small application to read/validate a file and update.
So I have this requirement to write some code for reading a fixed length file, validating it and then if it is valid upload it to Database.

I got everything working until I got stuck with the `AutoResetEvent`. So here is what is happening. Once the data is parsed/read I validate it using Flat File Checker utility in C#. So I called the functions into my application. Here is the snippet.

```
private AutoResetEvent do_checks = new AutoResetEvent(false);
public bool ValidationComplete = false;
```

This part goes in initialization code:

```
this._files.Validated += new EventHandler<SchemaValidatedEventArgs>(FileSetValidated);

public bool ValidateFile()
{
    try
    {
        RunValidation(); 
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error("Data Validation failed because :" + e.Message);
        return false;
    }
}

private void RunValidation()
{
    // Use Flat File Checker user interface to create Schema file.
    do_checks = _files.RunChecks();
    log.Debug("Validation Started");
}
```

This is the method that is getting called asnchronusly during the validation process:

```
public void FileSetValidated(Object sender, SchemaValidatedEventArgs e)
{   
    try
    {                 
        ValidationComplete = e.Result;

        if (IsDataValid)
        {
            log.Debug("Data is validated and found to be valid.");
        }
        else
        {
            log.Debug("Data is validated and found to be Invalid");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        do_checks.Set();
    }
}
```

What is happening is that even before I get any value set into `ValidationComplete` the code is checked for Validation complete and because it is set by default to false, it returns false. The code in the `FileSetValidated` gets executed after that so the database update never happens.

The reason is that I cannot change the code because the Flat File Checker only accepts an `AutoResetEvent` as a return variable in RunChecks method.

*********Here is what I did now******************
    private AutoResetEvent do_checks;

```
public bool ValidateFile()
    {

        try
        {

            string extFilePath = surveyFile.ExtFilePath;
            File.Copy(extFilePath, localTempFolder + "ExtractFile.Dat");
            RunValidation();

            if (!do_checks.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))) { 

            //    throw new  ApplicationException("Validation took more than expected!"); 
            }    

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("Data Validation failed because :" + e.Message);
            return false;

        }



    }


    private void RunValidation()
    {
        // Use Flat File Checker user interface to create Schema file.
        do_checks = _files.RunChecks();
        do_checks.WaitOne();
        log.Debug("Validation Started");


    }
```

Also I moved the part where data about validation gets passed on towards the beginning of the event handler so atleast that part gets executed. This helped but I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: There are some pieces missing here. You are creating the do_checks event, but then later on you assign what RunChecks() returns, thus overwriting what you created earlier. You say above that RunValidation only accepts an AutoResetEvent, but RunValidation is yours and doesn't accept anything. RunChecks returns one. It's possible that you're supposed to wait on what RunChecks returns.

Comment: Thanks !!!You are correct that RunChecks is returning AutoReset event. So I am using this AutoReset event at various places. How do I reference it in different functions? So I just defined it without assigning and later when RunChecks returns I assign it. Do you think thats correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never worked with that lib, so I just downloaded it and looked into the code.

First of all, as "500 - Internal Server Error" already mentioned, it seems that part of the code is missing, at least "try" in the FileSetValidated method. I don't see any place where you are waiting for the event via **WaitOne**.

You don't need to create **do_checks** by yourself, because **_files.RunChecks()** creates AutoResetEven for this particular file's processing. So if you are using the same field for that event - you will get issue if you will need to process few files at the same time. So keep separate event for each file, in any case I don't see reason to keep that references as members if you don't want to stop processing in the middle (if you will call **do_checks.Set()** during processing, it will cancel processing without finishing it).

As I see in the lib code, you should not call **do_checks.Set()** in the **FileSetValidated** method, because it will be set, once processing will be done, so you can just write:

```
var do_checks = _files.RunChecks();
do_checks.WaitOne();
```

Feel free to share if that helped.

**UPDATE:**
I am not able to check that lib now to undestand why **do_checks** is set after starting processing, but I can suggest you to use your initial code with next **RunValidation** method:

```
private void RunValidation()
{
    do_checks.Reset(); //reset state
    _files.RunChecks(); //don't store event from the lib
    log.Debug("Validation Started");
    do_checks.WaitOne(); //Wait for FileSetValidated to set this event
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had tried to add WaitOne at various places but it doid not seem to work so I got rid of it. So when I add the above to my code still the Validation happens randomly. Sometime I get what I want sometimes I dont. So this what is what I did:Declared Autoreset event, used with runchecks and added waitone. and added the answer given in revious post in runvalidation(). So it does executes the part where I know if Data is valid or not and then remaining like updating database asynchronously. Hope I am doing it correctly. Thanks

Comment: You should leave only one WaitOne - in the **ValidateFile** or in the **RunValidation**. That's why you are getting Exception for any time in the `if (!do_checks.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))) {`

Comment: If I get rid of either one of them, the program does not wait for validation to happen.  Let me run some tests today and see. Thanks again.  Also I want to put both as answers. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Please, check UPDATE section in my post, hope that helps.

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned in the updated section. It did validation before the database update but seemed to come out of the loop. It looked like it was running all the time. Then I just called do_checks.set in the FileSetValidated event handler and it worked great. So do you think this way is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Before exiting the ValidateFile function you need to wait for the validation to complete (wait on the AutoResetEvent) and return the validation result.

Try something like this:

```
public bool ValidateFile()
{
    //try
    {
        RunValidation();

        //Allocate enough time for the validation to occur but make sure 
        // the application doesn't block if the _files.Validated event doesn't get fired
        if(!do_checks.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
        {
            throw ApplicationException("Validation took more than expected!");
        }            

        return ValidationComplete;
    }
    //I would not catch the exception since having an error doesn't mean that the file 
    //is invalid. Catch it upper in the call stack and inform the user that the validation 
    //could not be performed because of the error
    //catch (Exception e)
    //{
    //     log.Error("Data Validation failed because :" + e.Message);
    //     return false;
    //}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I tried this example so I always get this ApplicationException no matter what I do I tried 10 secs 20 secs 30 secs. but what I did was I combined both the answers this and one below and writted. I will post it .But this piece of code will give the code to wait till the validation happens.